# How to denote primary key and foreign key in my entity relationship diagram?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database and i want to generate ER (entity relationship) diagrams
  for the database. I have tables and foreign key relation to the other tables
  how to mention these relation ship in my ER diagrams?

I am new to ER diagrams can you tell me?what is the best way to design?

can u tell me ER diagrams only for database?

I have one table it contains nearly 32 fields all the fields is mandatory to
  mentioned in ER diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check  [This Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1790223.aspx?Making%20ER%20Diagram%20from%20SQL%20Server%202008%20Database) for your query , by this link these are the steps.

Follow these steps.

1.Go to Sql Server Management Studio ->Object Explorer->Databases->Database Node(The node which will have your databse name).

2.Under your database node you will find a node named Database Diagrams along with node for Tables,Views etc.

3.Right Click on "Database Diagrams" node and select new database diagram and it will launch a wizard to generate Database diagram.

This Diagram will contain all tables along with their keys and relationships.

Comment: Is database diagrams are nothing but Er diagrams? I don't know can you tell me?

Comment: there are some differences but it will solve your purpose as per your question i think.

Comment: ok i generated database diagrams. fine can you tell me how to design er diagrams. means there is rectangle box for denote entity and eclipse for denote an attributes in an entity.like that can u tell me how to denote for primary key and foreignkey while designing Er diagrams?

Comment: And also which is the best tool for design these diagrams?Thanks @viplock

Comment: yo can use ERwin for it. get more details from here [Link](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm)

Comment: i thinnk @viplock. is the above Er diagrams is enough for showing relationships to the client?

Comment: yes as per my exp. its enough for showing relationship .

Comment: Thanks dude i generated Er diagrams just like you mentioned the above process (In SQL) Thanks